# transforming data in hive tables before inserting into another table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have here a table in hive.

```
 CREATE external TABLE apacheLogs4( 
     ip STRING, 
     instance STRING, 
     time STRING, 
     request STRING, 
     status STRING, 
     size STRING, 
     referer STRING, 
     agent STRING, 
     last STRING) 
     ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
     WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
     "input.regex" = "\"([^ ]*)\" ([^ ]*) - - \\[(.*)\\] ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\") (-|[0-9]*) (-|      [0-9]*) ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\") ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\") ([^ ]*)",
     "output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s %8$s %9$s" 
     ) 
      STORED AS TEXTFILE 
    LOCATION '/home/~user/Documents/apache_logs2'
```

I am applying regex to ip and agent to extract the country and browser type for each record, before inserting those records into a new table.

How do I do that in hive?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating UDFS to achieve this

Refer..

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HivePlugins